# Is a foreign (non-US) passport acceptable identification to purchase alcohol in Tenneseee?

Tags: usa, passports, paperwork, alcohol

I am a cashier at a Walmart in Tennessee. I was instructed by management that we can only accept identification that has been issued by the US Federal Government or a state government.

Two days ago, a person attempted to purchase alcohol with his Salvadoran passport. One of my co-workers said that this was now acceptable identification for purchasing alcohol, and I allowed it.

I mentioned this to another co-worker, who reprimanded me, claiming that the law had not changed.

Is a foreign (non-US) passport considered acceptable identification to purchase alcohol in Tennessee?

Comment: Hi Steven. This site is about travel, and this isn't really a question about travel. If you want to know about the law, then we have a [Law site](http://law.stackexchange.com) where you could ask. Or if you wanted to know how to handle the conflict between managers we have a [Workplace site](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @DJClayworth is correct.  [Law.SE] is the place to go to find out what the law says, but as an employee you should probably follow the instructions of your direct supervisor.  The question of what to do with conflicting instructions could be on topic on both Law and [Workplace.SE].

Comment: I only posted this here because of a question I found on google that was about acceptable ID for alcohol sales, pertaining to what was accepted, versus being an ID from a foreign government.

Comment: The travel angle in that question comes from the fact that travelers may want to buy alcohol.  You could recast your question in those terms, but you're probably going to get a more useful answer from one of the other sites.

Comment: For what its worth i've bought alcohol from Walmart in Utah for years with a British passport

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about travel.

Comment: Not an answer, because I think the question should be closed: [Am I required by state law to check the identification of a person purchasing alcoholic beverages?](https://www.tn.gov/abc/public-information-and-forms/frequently-asked-questions.html) specifically allows foreign government issued identification which includes a photo and date of birth.

Comment: @BritishSam it's not worth very much since these matters fall under state law.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan that doesn't address whether the law has changed recently.

Comment: Even if not off-topic, this question is too long and difficult to read with "/sarcasm" and "CSM" and "CBL" and a plot with managers. It could be summarized in one sentence: "Does state law in Tennessee permit alcohol sales with a foreign passport?"

Comment: The law clearly only asks for 'Government Issued IDs', not for 'US-government issued IDs': https://publications.tnsosfiles.com/rules/0100/0100-11.20171115.pdf

Comment: @Aganju You are linking to the Alcoholic Beverage Commision rules and not the law, which is even vaguer in the wording. According to the Tennesee Code (§ 57-3-406), a government-issued *document* with photo and date of birth is sufficient. There are also exceptions. e.g. for persons exempt under state law from having a photo identification document, who 'shall present identification that is acceptable to the retailer'. Finally, 'the retailer or employee shall make a determination from the information presented whether the purchaser is an adult.'

Comment: I don't see why this question is off-topic. While it is being asked from the perspective of a US worker, the question can be rephrased as "Can a foreigner purchase alcohol in a store in Tennessee using their non-US passport?" I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: I edited the question to more clearly indicate what the actual question is and remove the fluff.

Comment: Not really off-topic, IMO. Imagine the question being: _I am a citizen of El Salvador. I will be traveling to the US, and only have my Salvadoran passport as identification. Can I use this as proof of my age to purchase alcohol in Tennessee?_

Comment: Because the answers to those questions could be different. They could point out the normal practice (which might be different from what the law required). And also because we can't accept any question just because 'a foreigner might ask it'.

Comment: https://www.tn.gov/safety/driver-services/dlidentify.html